# Can a spell cast outside a primal magic area affect its interior?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, primal

The question divides in two possibilities:

1. A spell is cast outside a primal magic area but the target/place is inside of it. Does it work?
2. A spell is cast outside a primal magic area but the target/place is outside of it, but the spell's area of effect still affects part of the area. Does it work?

The example that came to my mind: a fireball cast to explode inside a primal magic area or outside of it, but the explosion still reaches people inside the area.

Comment: You mean primal magic described here: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/primal-magic/ ?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no chance of Primal Magic Substitution

> When a creature activates a magic item, casts a spell, or uses a spell-like ability in an area infused with primal magic, there’s a 50% chance that the spell effect is replaced by a primal magic effect.

Since what matters is where the caster is, not where the spell effect occurs, casting from outside the area avoids any chance of triggering a primal magic effect.  However, the boundaries of primal magic areas are not normally described as precise lines, so making use of this over short distances may be ineffectual.